# Is energy an independent object or a property of objects?

Tags: energy, education

I am just learning, so the question may seem silly. I asked my teacher, is energy a separate object or a property of objects? And he replied that depending on the context, it could be either. Further he did not want to go into details. I understand how energy can be a quantitative property of objects. But how can energy itself be an independent object, in what context?

Comment: One could possibly consider an object to "be" energy related through $E=mc^2$

Comment: @Jonas Do not understand.

Comment: What do you mean by an object? Energy is a number, do you consider numbers to be objects?

Comment: Obligatory reading from the [Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html).

Comment: @jacob1729 I mean any physical object, any physical system - a stone, the Sun, a galaxy, an atom, a photon, quarks ... Is energy a quantitative property of such objects?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress One considers energy and mass to be somewhat the same, but in different states. The energy you get when converting a mass $m$ into matter is $E=mc^2$

Answer (score 4):

Energy is a property of an object such as a field or a particle or a collection of particles. It is not unique in this respect - there are many other properties in physics, such as mass, velocity, acceleration, momentum, charge, spin, pressure, temperature, volume etc.etc.